# Student learning C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that ask for a movie title, adult tickets sold, and children tickets sold, the 1st question pauses but the 2nd and 3rd are put together

```
// This program displays a theaters profits

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const double ADULT_TICKET = 6.00;
const double CHILD_TICKET = 3.00;
const double PERCENT_GROSS_BOX_PROFIT = 0.20;

int main()
{
    double adult_Ticketsold, child_Ticketsold, Grossboxprofit, distributorPrice,
        Netboxprofit, AdultTotal, ChildTotal;
    string movieTitle;


    cout << "Which movie had the highest ticket sales tonight? ";
    cin >> movieTitle;
    cout << "How many adult tickets did we sell tonight? ";
    cin >> adult_Ticketsold;
    cout << "How many tickets for children? ";
    cin >> child_Ticketsold;

    AdultTotal = ADULT_TICKET * adult_Ticketsold;
    ChildTotal = CHILD_TICKET * child_Ticketsold;
    Grossboxprofit = AdultTotal + ChildTotal;
    Netboxprofit = (AdultTotal + ChildTotal) * PERCENT_GROSS_BOX_PROFIT;
    distributorPrice = Grossboxprofit - Netboxprofit;

    cout << left << setw(15) << "Movie Name: " << right << setw(12) << movieTitle << endl;
    cout << left << setw(25) << "Adult Tickets Sold: " << right << setw(4) << adult_Ticketsold <<     endl;
    cout << left << setw(25) << "Child Tickets Sold: " << right << setw(4) << child_Ticketsold <<   endl;
    cout << left << setw(40) << "Gross Box Office Profit: " << " S " << setprecision(2) <<
        right << fixed << setw(12) << Grossboxprofit << endl;
    cout << left << setw(45) << "Amount Paid to Distributor: " << " $ " << setprecision(2) <<
        right << fixed << setw(12) << distributorPrice << endl;
    cout << left << setw(18) << "Net Box Office Profit: " << " $ " << setprecision(2) <<
        right << fixed << setw(12) << Netboxprofit << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

the output shows

Which movie had the highest ticket sales?  Avengers
How many adult tickets did we sell? How many tickets did we sell for children.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce it - it works for me with Avengers title.

Comment: If you want to read a line, use a function that reads a line.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `cin >> moveTitle` will only read the first whitespace-delimiter word into `movieTitle`: if you type say "Life of Brian", then you'll have `Life` in `movieTitle` and `cin >> adult_Ticketsold` will choke and fail on `" of Brian"`.  (If you'd used a debugger, added `std::cout << "movieTitle " << movieTitle << '\n';`, or checked `std::cin` for failure state after input operations you'd have noticed ;-P).

To read a line through to the newline:

```
if (!std::getline(std::cin, movieTitle))
{
    std::cerr << "error reading movieTitle\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```